# Multiple forms with one submit button with edit and delete button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

How to submit and "show"(in the same page) multiple form with one submit button with edit and delete button with php javascript?

This is my mockup

[image: This is my mockup]

This is my code without php:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Content number</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="BranchName" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Topic</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Tel" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Content</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="Address" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p id="submit">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help. This is the final that what i expect. I want it to clear text area after click submit to be ready for the new form.  But now i don't know how to show all form that submitted at the bottom of the page in list of item with edit and delete function.

Comment: Is this a PHP, an HTML or a JavaScript question?

Comment: Call where this form gets put into php using ajax and get returning value then appended to the div where you want to show information.

Answer (score 1):

As i'm assuming your getting your information via PHP, what you will need to do in the edit/ delete sections is add some form item id for the edit/delete functions something like. Alternatively you can do the same thing in JavaScript, and link the AJAX request to a .php file with the functions for handling the edit and delete functions.

```
<?php foreach($key as $data) { ?>

  <form action="edit.php" method="post">
   <input name="<?php echo $data[$key].formItemID ?>" type="submit" value="edit" />
  </form>
  <form action="delete.php" method="post">
   <input name="<?php echo $data[$key].formItemID ?>" type="submit" value="delete" />
  </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: now i don't know how to show all form that submitted at the bottom of the page

Comment: You will have to get that in an Ajax request from your database where the submitted form data is stored. In my example i represented this as `$data`